# Remove-ItemProperty does not support credentials

Tags: powershell, registry

I tried  to remove registry object using admin credentials by powershell

```
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User,$pass

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Remove-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\outlook\security" -Name "clearsign" -Credential $Credential}
```

But i got en error below:

```
The provider does not support the use of credentials. Perform the operation again without specifying credentials.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\1 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotImplemented: (:) [], PSNotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupported
```

Based on what microsoft [documentation](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-itemproperty?view=powershell-7) says i have to do use -credentials with Invoke command since it is not supprted , but its still not working

any suggestion how i suppose to do it  ?

Comment: You need to supply the credential object to `Invoke-Command`: `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Remove-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\outlook\security" -Name "clearsign"} -Credential $Credential`

Comment: Hi, thanks for suggestion. I still get an Error : Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.

Comment: Add `-ComputerName localhost` to `Invoke-Command`.